# laravel errors on using Models in custom files

Tags: laravel, model

I have a custom file in my laravel project. I registered this file in composer.json and also I enter these command to refresh composer :

```
composer clear-cache
composer dump-auto
```

the excerpt code of my this custom file is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App;
use App\Rss;
dd(Rss::all());
```

I give this errors when I enter 
    php artisan

> php fatal error : Uncaught Error : call to a member function connection() on null in .....\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Database\Eloquent\Model.php (1101 ,  931 ، 877 ، 840 ، 363)

please help me

Comment: please give more details: where is the code in the file structure? where is the Rss class ? My guess id the issue is related to Rss

Comment: @Indra The helper file that I want to use Models is in App folder.  App\helpers.php and also Rss model is in App folder

Comment: did you set your .env file?

Comment: This seems to be a setup issue. Your database connection is not set or wrongly set. If you believe the data in .env is correct, run `php artisan config:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: @Indra the config of .env file is ok

Comment: @DimitriMostrey I try your solution but the problem is not solved

Comment: @SaeedRahimimanesh sorry to hear that. What happens if you run the `App\Rss::all()` command in `php artisan tinker`?

Comment: @DimitriMostrey when I exactly enter : App\Rss::all() , I give All Rss rows from rss Table.

Comment: So in tinker it works. Now, the file you are presenting in your question, where does it reside? It seems a Model file, as the namespace is App. Is the namespace correct? And how do you get to this file? What is the route to load it? Try it as a Controller function and see if it works out.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey the patch of my helper file is in : App\helper.php and the namespace that I wrote is : namespace App;   I want to write some global function in this file like a function to check some coloumns of a table. theses are some functions and not Controller that I have use Routes.... if I use controller I should write my functions in class? and I have to create object from class? can I access to this object from other php files?

Comment: If you get your Models right, they are accessable anywhere in your code (Model::....) I use personalized functions too. Is the file added to composer.json? `"files": [
      "app/helper.php"],`

Comment: @DimitriMostrey yes the file added to composer.json corectly

Comment: Honestly my friend, I'm out of ideas. Your composer.json is correct, .env is correct, it works in tinker but somehow not in your function. This issue is a mystery to me. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. I hope somebody else can figure it our for you.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey thank u so much for your help, dear dimitri...♥

Comment: Ok, one more idea. Run `dd(\config::get('database'));` in your function and `\Config:get('database')` in tinker. I wonder if there is any difference.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey I give these errors : 
1 - uncaught Error : class 'config' not found in global.php
2 - patchofproject\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(66): require()

Comment: @DimitriMostrey but when I enter the command in php artisan, I see the database connection details

Comment: Hmmm, so laravel doesn't boot correctly if you run it in the browser. Not sure how that is possible. It seems you don't follow the rules of vmc, you probably bypass the routing part. Is it possible you try to reach this function without a route? The same bootsequence is used in tinker and that works. My guess is there is something wrong in routes/web.php

Comment: You already ran `composer dump-autoload` right? Run `composer selfupdate` and `composer install --prefer-dist -vvv` followed by `composer check`. Copy the check returns in your question above.

Comment: If that doesn't work, you will have to reinstall laravel all together, copy your web.php, model, controller and view files over there and try again. To pinpoint why the config() function is not found when run in a browser will be very hard.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey after more search I found that the custom files load before laravel project. it means I cant access the models before DB connection start. for this reason I give error on null connection